# Issue with verifying correct age in html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I want to make sure that an age is correct with the year born, where both values are submitted in an html form, in accordance to the current year.
However, upon inputting a value that wouldn't satisfy my claims it doesn't give me an alert.

```js
function formError() {

  if (document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
    alert('Please enter your name.');
    document.getElementById('name').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('yearborn').value == "") {
    alert('Please enter the year you were born.');
    document.getElementById('yearborn').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('age').value == "") {
    alert('Please enter your age.');
    document.getElementById('age').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
  }

  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getFullYear();
  var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
  var yearBorn = getElementById('yearborn').value;

  if (n - age !== yearBorn) {
    alert('Please make sure that your age and year born is correct.');
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <form id="frmName" method=post action="#" onsubmit="return formError()">
    <h1>Inf115 compulsory assignment 3</h1>
    <p>
      <b>Name:</b><input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="20" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <b>Year of birth:</b><input type=int id="yearborn" maxlength="4" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <b>Age:</b><input type=int id="age" maxlength="3" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </p>
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Typo: `var yearBorn = document.getElementById('yearborn').value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. missing document in document.getElementById
2. mistake in age - it is possible the user is not yet n - yearBorn
3. Invalid HTML, fieldset should be inside the form
4. I strongly suggest an eventListener and to reset the colour before error

If you do not want the suggestions, then

```
    const diff = n - yearBorn - age ;
    if (diff !== 0 && diff !== 1) {
```

is enough

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("frmName").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

    const errors = [];
    let obj;

    obj = document.getElementById('name');
    obj.classList.toggle("error", 0)
    if (obj.value == "") {
      errors.push('Please enter your name.');
      obj.classList.toggle("error", 1)
    }

    obj = document.getElementById('yearborn');
    obj.classList.toggle("error", 0)
    if (obj.value == "") {
      errors.push('Please enter the year you were born.');
      obj.classList.toggle("error", 1)
    }

    obj = document.getElementById('age');
    obj.classList.toggle("error", 0)
    if (document.getElementById('age').value == "") {
      errors.push('Please enter your age.');
      obj.classList.toggle("error", 1)
    }

    const n = new Date().getFullYear();
    const age = +document.getElementById('age').value;
    const yearBorn = +document.getElementById('yearborn').value;
    const diff = n - yearBorn - age ;
    if (diff !== 0 && diff !== 1) {
      errors.push('Please make sure that your age and year born is correct.');
      obj.classList.toggle("error", 1)
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      alert(errors.join("\n"));
      e.preventDefault();
    }  

  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="frmName" method=post action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <h1>Inf115 compulsory assignment 3</h1>
    <p>
      <b>Name:</b><input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="20" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <b>Year of birth:</b><input type=int id="yearborn" maxlength="4" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <b>Age:</b><input type=int id="age" maxlength="3" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```